# Is usage of someone else's bank card allowed?

Tags: banking, bank-account, debit-card, cash

If I gave my bank debit card from Payoneer with my name on it (but no photo and signature) to friend of mine, is he allowed to withdraw money from my card in the branch of the bank using Cash Desk(Teller)?

Presumably he knows my PIN and everything.

Would there be any questions for him on why he is using the card of another person?

Comment: What's "Cash desk"?  In any event, I imagine this is up to the bank's specific policies; certainly some banks (if not most) would reject it, at least according to their policies.

Comment: @Joe By "Cash desk" I mean the place where cashier gives you money, not usage of ATM. Maybe cashbox will sound better.

Comment: Teller is common word in the US, I'm not sure where you are.  But - why not use the ATM?

Comment: Thanks. In some Eastern European countries there are no US dollar ATMs at all, that's why such a difficulties.

Comment: Legal questions should specify the jurisdiction.

Comment: Is it legal for him to withdraw money if you allowed it? Probably yes. Is it legal for him to withdraw money if you don't allow it? Maybe yes, maybe no. Is it legal for the bank to refuse to pay money to him? Absolutely. Might they call the police to investigate? Quite possibly. And then we are back to question 1 and 2. But by handing him your card, you might be acting against the T&Cs of the bank and be responsible for any loss if he empties your account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, this choice is entirely up to the bank itself. There was a time when, given my mothers ATM card I could go to the bank and pull money for her, but the bank has since changed their rules and now they only will allow people listed on the account to access it, card or no card.

If the bank is aware of who you are and knows that your friend is not you, they may be skeptical of allowing your friend to withdraw any money, or they might not care, it's at their discretion.

If they do not know who either of you are, if your friend has the card and information needed, that will likely be sufficient, unless they ask for identification.

Comment: It might help if your friend is carrying signed authorization from you to withdraw a specific amount -- essentially, an unofficial check. Of course if you wrote a real check to your friend, he could cash it against his own account and wouldn't need access to yours.